# When Android app is not in focus but running the app becomes shaky

Tags: android, user-interface, service, focus

I have written an Android app that plays audio.
When the app is in focus (its UI is visible by user) the app works as expected and the audio is nice and solid. When the app is not in focus (user leaves the app's UI) but it is still running I hear the audio but it is shaky meaning if I open another app I see some choppiness in the audio for 1 second then it goes away.

What should I do to make sure even when my app is running in the back ground it is not disturbed with the operation other apps?

I am thinking this may be the place one should use services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best way to do this is to use a service.